# Is there an equivalent to R apply function in Python?

Tags: python, r, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find the Python equivalent to R's `apply` function but with multidimensional arrays.

For example, when called the following code:

```
z <- array(1, dim = 2:4)
apply(z, 1, sum)
```

The result is:

```
[1] 12 12
```

and when called with two values for margin:

```
apply(z, c(1,2), sum)
```

The result is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    4    4
[2,]    4    4    4
```

I found that the `sum` function in numpy can be used, but not in the same consistent way:

For example:

```
import numpy as np

xx= np.ones((2,3,4))
np.sum(xx,axis=(1,2))
```

The result is:

```
array([12., 12.])
```

but I can't find a function that equivalent to `apply` in its manner specifically when dealing with `margin=c(1,2)`. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent in NumPy is:

```
xx.sum(axis=2)
```

That is, you are summing over axis 2 (the last dimension), which as its length is 4, leaves the other two dimensions (2,3) as the shape of the result:

```
array([[4., 4., 4.],
       [4., 4., 4.]])
```

Perhaps a more literal translation of your R code would be:

```
np.apply_over_axes(np.sum, xx, 2)
```

Which gives a similar result but transposed.  This is likely to be slower, however, and is not idiomatic unless the actual operation you're performing is something more complicated than sum.

Comment: I was using np.apply_along_axis until I discovered this

Answer (score 1):

`np.apply_over_axes` is different from R's `apply` in several ways.

First, `np.apply_over_axes` needs collapsing axes to be specified,
whereas R's `apply` needs remaining axes to be specified.

Secondly, `np.apply_over_axes` applies function iteratively as [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_over_axes.html?highlight=apply_over_axes) stated below. The result is the same for `np.sum` but it could be different for other functions.

> func is called as res = func(a, axis), where axis is the first element of axes. The result res of the function call must have either the same dimensions as a or one less dimension. If res has one less dimension than a, a dimension is inserted before axis. The call to func is then repeated for each axis in axes, with res as the first argument.

And the func for `np.apply_over_axes` needs to be in particular format and the return of func needs to be in particular shape for `np.apply_over_axes` to perform correctly.

Here's an example how `np.apply_over_axes` fails

```
>>> arr.shape
(5, 4, 3, 2)
>>> np.apply_over_axes(np.mean, arr, (0,1))
array([[[[ 0.05856732, -0.14844212],
         [ 0.34214183,  0.24319846],
         [-0.04807454,  0.04752829]]]])
>>> np_mean = lambda x: np.mean(x)
>>> np.apply_over_axes(np_mean, arr, (0,1))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in apply_over_axes
  File "/Users/kwhkim/opt/miniconda3/envs/rtopython2-pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 495, in apply_over_axes
    res = func(*args)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Since there seems to be no equivalent function in Python,
I made a function that is similar to R's `apply`

```
def np_apply(arr, axes_remain, fun, *args, **kwargs):
    axes_remain = tuple(set(axes_remain))
    arr_shape = arr.shape
    axes_to_move = set(range(len(arr.shape)))
    for axis in axes_remain:
        axes_to_move.remove(axis)
    axes_to_move = tuple(axes_to_move)
    arr, axes_to_move
    arr2 = np.moveaxis(arr, axes_to_move, [-x for x in list(range(1,len(axes_to_move)+1))]).copy()
    #if arr2.flags.c_contiguous:
    arr2 = arr2.reshape([arr_shape[x] for x in axes_remain]+[-1])

    return np.apply_along_axis(fun, -1, arr2, *args, **kwargs)
```

It works fine at least for the sample example as above(not exactly the same as the result above but `math.close()` returns True for nearly all elements)

```
>>> np_apply(arr, (2,3), np.mean)
array([[ 0.05856732, -0.14844212],
       [ 0.34214183,  0.24319846],
       [-0.04807454,  0.04752829]])
>>> np_apply(arr, (2,3), np_mean)
array([[ 0.05856732, -0.14844212],
       [ 0.34214183,  0.24319846],
       [-0.04807454,  0.04752829]])
```

For the function to work smoothly for large multidimensional array,
it needs to be optimized. For instance,
array should be prevented from copying.

Anyway it seems to work as a proof-of-concept and I hope it helps.

PS)
`arr` is generated by `arr = np.random.normal(0,1,(5,4,3,2))`